# Gtk FlowBox - buttons in box clickable area tiny

Tags: python, gtk, gtkflowbox

I've created a GtkFlowBox into which I've added a load of buttons and am trying to catch clicks on these buttons with a function which, for the moment, simply outputs the selected button. However, the actual clickable area of each button is minuscule - you need to click right in the corner of the button for it to register.

I can't seem to find any options to extend the clickable area of children in the GtkFlowBox class, nor in the GtkButton class. Below is a minimum working example to demonstrate.

```
class NotebookWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="FlowBox Test")

        #Create Application Window
        self.set_border_width(10)
        self.set_default_size(800, 600)
        self.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER)

        #Add external container (box)
        vbox = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, spacing=6)
        self.add(vbox)

        #Add tabbed window
        self.nbook = Gtk.Notebook()
        vbox.pack_start(self.nbook, True, True, 0)
        self.nbook.show()

        #Add Clubs tab
        frame = Gtk.Frame()
        frame.show()

        vbox = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, spacing=6)

        club_box = Gtk.FlowBox()
        club_box.set_valign(Gtk.Align.START)
        club_box.set_max_children_per_line(30)
        club_box.set_selection_mode(Gtk.SelectionMode.SINGLE)
        club_box.set_activate_on_single_click(True)

        for club in range(0, 55):
            button = Gtk.Button(club)
            club_box.add(button)

        vbox.pack_start(club_box, True, True, 0)

        self.out_message = Gtk.Label("\n")
        vbox.add(self.out_message)

        label = Gtk.Label()
        label.set_markup("<b><big>Clubs</big></b>")

        frame.add(vbox)

        club_box.connect("child-activated", self.on_club_details)

        self.nbook.append_page(frame, label)


    def on_club_details(self, club_box, child):
        print "clicked club box %d" % child.get_index()


win = NotebookWindow()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()


Gtk.main()
```

Comment: I don't quite follow. Are you saying you need to click on the corner of the buttons to get the GtkFlowBox's `child-activated` to work?

Comment: yes, that's exactly it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you actually want is to register clicks on the buttons and not when they are activated. A button is not necessarily activated as soon as it is clicked.

I simplified your code a bit but this is what I think you want to achieve:

```
class NotebookWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="FlowBox Test")

        #Create Application Window
        self.set_border_width(10)
        self.set_default_size(400, 400)
        self.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER)

        #Add tabbed window
        self.nbook = Gtk.Notebook()
        self.add(self.nbook)

        vbox = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, spacing=6)

        club_box = Gtk.FlowBox()
        club_box.set_valign(Gtk.Align.START)
        club_box.set_max_children_per_line(30)
        club_box.set_selection_mode(Gtk.SelectionMode.SINGLE)
        club_box.set_activate_on_single_click(True)

        self.buttons = []
        for club in range(0, 55):
            button = Gtk.Button(label=club)
            club_box.add(button)
            button.connect('clicked', self.on_button_clicked)  # new callback
            self.buttons.append(button)

        vbox.pack_start(club_box, True, True, 0)

        self.out_message = Gtk.Label(label="\n")
        vbox.pack_start(self.out_message, True, True, 0)

        label = Gtk.Label()
        label.set_markup("<b><big>Clubs</big></b>")
        self.nbook.append_page(vbox, label)


    def on_button_clicked(self, button):
        for i in range(len(self.buttons)):
            if self.buttons[i] == button:
                print('button at index {}'.format(i))
                break


win = NotebookWindow()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()


Gtk.main()
```

Comment: That works fine - it picks up the label entry.Ideally, I want the button's position index to be passed but I can work with this.

Comment: I changed the code so now it stores the buttons in a list and looks up the index when the callback is emitted

Comment: i made a change just by adding 'club' (from the for-loop) as an extra parameter to the click-function call. I'm just trying to think if there's any scenario where the index will not match the value of club.